# Проблемы с событием hidden.bs.modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

В модальном окне "Вход" (Bootstrap) имеются две ссылки "Войти" и "Регистрация".
При клике на которых появляется соответствующее модальное окно.

При появлении второго модального окна, первый должен закрыться.

У Bootstrap для этого используется следующее:

- hidden.bs.modal - срабатывает когда модальное окно закрылось.
- $('elem').modal('hide') - закрыть окно.

Код следующий:

```
    function toggleModal(elem, modalEl) {
        var idModal;

        idModal = $(elem).attr('data-target');
        $(modalEl).modal('hide');
        $(modalEl).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            idModal = $(elem).attr('data-target');
            $(idModal).modal('show');
        });
    }

    var userAuthModal = $('#order-pa__log');
    var userIdentif = userAuthModal.find('.order-pa__reglinks');

    userIdentif.on( 'click', { userAuthModal : userAuthModal }, userAuth );

    function userAuth (event) {
        var target,
            userAuthModal,
            forgotEl,
            regEl;

        target = event.target;
        userAuthModal = event.data.userAuthModal;

        forgotEl = target.closest('.modal-forgot');
        regEl = target.closest('.modal-reg');

        if (forgotEl) {
            toggleModal(forgotEl, userAuthModal);
        } else if (regEl) {
            toggleModal(regEl, userAuthModal);
        }
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том что при каждом открытии нового окна hidden.bs.modal срабатывает столько сколько было открыто модальных окон. Не понимаю почему так происходит и как от этого избавится.

Comment: Попробуйте очистить очередь - `.clearQueue()`

Comment: Как я понимаю нужно написать так:
        function toggleModal(elem, modalEl) {
            var idModal;

            idModal = $(elem).attr('data-target');
            $(modalEl).modal('hide');
            $(modalEl).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                idModal = $(elem).attr('data-target');
                $(idModal).modal('show');
            });
            $(modalEl).clearQueue();
        }
Но, это не помогло.

Comment: Просто понять бы почему такое поведение, не хотелось "костылить".

Comment: нет, чистить очередь нужно в самом начале, а не в конце

Comment: не сказала бы, что `.clearQueue()`  костыль

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, жаль.

Comment: сделайте [mcve], чтобы можно было увидеть, а не гадать

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте ссылке `data-dismiss="modal"`. Вот, что называется минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```js
function toggleModal(elem, modalEl) {
  var idModal;

  idModal = $(elem).attr('data-target');
  $(modalEl).modal('hide');
  $(modalEl).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    idModal = $(elem).attr('data-target');
    $(idModal).modal('show');
  });
}

var userAuthModal = $('#order-pa__log');
var userIdentif = userAuthModal.find('.order-pa__reglinks');

userIdentif.on('click', {
  userAuthModal: userAuthModal
}, userAuth);

function userAuth(event) {
  var target,
    userAuthModal,
    forgotEl,
    regEl;

  target = event.target;
  userAuthModal = event.data.userAuthModal;

  forgotEl = target.closest('.modal-forgot');
  regEl = target.closest('.modal-reg');

  if (forgotEl) {
    toggleModal(forgotEl, userAuthModal);
  } else if (regEl) {
    toggleModal(regEl, userAuthModal);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal 1</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2" data-dismiss="modal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal 2</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите решили ли данную проблему ?